# Integrate out (covariance) matrix in Normal-Wishart distribution

Tags: bayesian, wishart-distribution, matrix-calculus

In Gelman's Bayesian Data Analysis Chapter 3.6, he introduces the multivariate normal with unknown mean and variance, with the priors

$\Sigma\sim \text{Inv-Wishart}_{\nu_0}(\Lambda_0^{-1})$

$\mu\rvert \Sigma \sim N(\mu_0, \Sigma/\kappa_0)$

and the joint prior

$p(\mu, \Sigma)\propto \lvert \Sigma\rvert^{-((\nu_0+d)/2+1)}\exp\Big(-\frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(\Lambda_0\Sigma^{-1})-\frac{\kappa_0}{2}(\mu-\mu_0)'\Sigma^{-1}(\mu-\mu_0)\Big)$

Gelman then states that the (posterior) marginal is multivariate $t$ without elaboration.

In a paper that I found (A Bayes Approach for Combining Correlated Estimates - Seymour Geisser), Geisser had the following steps, also without elaboration (notations, parameterisation and context are different from Gelman, but a similar integration step is involved).

$p(\mu, \Sigma^{-1})\propto \Big\lvert \Sigma^{-1}\Big\rvert ^{(n-d-1)/2}\exp\Big(-\frac{1}{2}\text{tr}\Big(\Sigma^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^n (\mathbf{x}_j-\mu\mathbf{e})(\mathbf{x}_j-\mu\mathbf{e})'\Big)\Big)$

Integrating out $\Sigma^{-1}$ yields

$p(\mu)\propto \Big\lvert \sum_{j=1}^n(\mathbf{x}_j-\mu\mathbf{e})(\mathbf{x}_j-\mu\mathbf{e})'\Big\rvert ^{-n/2}$

The result can be further massaged to yield the $t$ density, but my question is specifically on the integration step only. The result $p(\mu)$ looks simple but I'm not sure how it's carried out.

***Question:*** How do I obtain the marginal distribution of $p(\mu)$ by integrating out $\Sigma$? Any references to similar matrix integrations will be great. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, notice that, if you use some properties of the trace operator,

\begin{align*}
p(\mu, \Sigma) &\propto \lvert \Sigma\rvert^{-((\nu_0+d)/2+1)}\exp\Big(-\frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(\Lambda_0\Sigma^{-1})-\frac{\kappa_0}{2}(\mu-\mu_0)'\Sigma^{-1}(\mu-\mu_0)\Big) \\
&= \lvert \Sigma\rvert^{-((\nu_0+d)/2+1)}\exp\Big(-\frac{1}{2}\text{tr}(\Lambda_0\Sigma^{-1})-\text{tr}\left(\frac{\kappa_0}{2}(\mu-\mu_0)(\mu-\mu_0)'\Sigma^{-1}\right)\Big) \\
&= \lvert \Sigma\rvert^{-((\nu_0+d)/2+1)}\exp\Big(-\frac{1}{2}\text{tr}\left\{\Lambda_0 + \kappa_0(\mu-\mu_0)(\mu-\mu_0)' \right\} \Sigma^{-1}\Big) \\
&= \lvert \Sigma\rvert^{-\left(\frac{[\nu_0+1] + d+1}{2}\right)}\exp\Big[-\frac{1}{2}\text{tr}\left( \Psi \Sigma^{-1} \right)\Big] \\
&= \lvert \Sigma\rvert^{-\left(\frac{\nu_1 + d+1}{2}\right)}\exp\Big[-\frac{1}{2}\text{tr}\left( \Psi \Sigma^{-1} \right)\Big]
\end{align*}

if you set $\Psi$ matrix to $\Lambda_0 + \kappa_0(\mu-\mu_0)(\mu-\mu_0)' $ and $\nu_1 = \nu_0 + 1$. So if you integrate with respect to $d \Sigma$, which is kind of misleading because all of the elements aren't unique, you'll get

$$
p(\mu) \propto \int \lvert \Sigma\rvert^{-\left(\frac{\nu_1 + d+1}{2}\right)}\exp\Big[-\frac{1}{2}\text{tr}\left( \Psi \Sigma^{-1} \right)\Big] d \Sigma = \frac{\Gamma_p(\nu_1/2) 2^{\nu_1p/2} }{\text{det}[\Psi]^{\nu_1/2}}.
$$

Technically, $d \Sigma$ is short hand for integrating with respect to the diagonal and the lower-half elements of $\Sigma$. This is because you're integrating over the space of positive definite, symmetric matrices. I can skip a lot of the details because I am just recognizing the Inverse-Wishart density and then looking up the normalizing constant on Wikipedia.

### Edit:

Just re-reading your question now and it looks like you're more interested in the marginal *posterior*. This is the marginal prior. You can use the same move, but I'll add the details in a little bit.

### Edit Number 2:

There are a few extra difficulties that I wanted to mention with the recognition of the $t$ density. This site doesn't have many answered questions like this, so I figured I could do it all out.

\begin{align*}
p(\mu) &\propto \text{det}\left(\Lambda_0 + \kappa_0(\mu-\mu_0)(\mu-\mu_0)'\right)^{-\frac{\nu_1}{2}} \\
&= \text{det}[\Lambda_0]^{-\frac{\nu_1}{2}} \text{det}\left(1 + \kappa_0(\mu-\mu_0)' \Lambda_0^{-1} (\mu-\mu_0)  \right)^{-\frac{\nu_1}{2}} \tag{*} \\
&\propto \text{det}\left(1 + \kappa_0(\mu-\mu_0)' \Lambda_0^{-1} (\mu-\mu_0)  \right)^{-\frac{\nu_1}{2}} \\
&= \text{det}\left(1 + \frac{1}{\nu_1 - p}(\mu-\mu_0)' \left[\frac{1}{[\nu_1 - p] \kappa_0}\Lambda_0\right]^{-1} (\mu-\mu_0)  \right)^{-\frac{[\nu_1-p]+p}{2}} \\
&\propto t_{\nu_1 - p}\left(\mu_0, \frac{1}{[\nu_1 - p] \kappa_0}\Lambda_0\right).
\end{align*}
where the line marked by the * follows by the matrix determinant lemma.

You might think that it's weird you lost a few degrees of freedom, but you can convince yourself it's true if you check the variance is what it should be. The variance of a $t_{\nu_1 - p}\left(\mu_0, \frac{1}{[\nu_1 - p] \kappa_0}\Lambda_0\right)$ is 
$$
\frac{1}{[\nu_1 - p] \kappa_0}\Lambda_0 \frac{\nu_1 - p}{\nu_1 - p-2} = \frac{1}{[\nu_1 - p-2] \kappa_0}\Lambda_0
$$
which is the same as the one we find with the law of total variance:
$$
E\left(\text{Var}\left[\mu \mid \Sigma \right]\right) = E[\Sigma]/\kappa_0
= \Lambda_0 \frac{1}{\kappa_0[\nu_0 - p - 1]}.
$$

Comment: Thank you! This is a sufficient answer. In my case, I simply did not recognise the integrand as a known distribution which leads to the integration result being the normalising constant. Your steps made it very clear, cheers!